# TypeError: ActiveSupport is not a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest, activesupport

Hello all and thanks in advance for the feedback.

I have a new rails 5.0.4 project (ruby 2.3.4p301 (2017-03-30 revision 58214) [x86_64-darwin15]) and am having an issue when running my first minitest pass.

The command:

```
bin/rails test
```

The error

```
TypeError: ActiveSupport is not a class
<sanatized>/ps/tekkedout-dnd-tools/test/test_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
<sanatized>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
<sanatized>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
<sanatized>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
<sanatized>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
<sanatized>/ps/tekkedout-dnd-tools/test/models/spell_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

test_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "rails/test_help"

class ActiveSupport
  class TestCase
    # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
    fixtures :all

    # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
  end
end
```

### Update

Looks like when implementing rubocop I made some hasty changes and hadn't started with my specs yet.

Here is the diff:

```
-class ActiveSupport::TestCase
-  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
-  fixtures :all
+class ActiveSupport
+  class TestCase
+    # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
+    fixtures :all

-  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
+    # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
+  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ActiveSupport` is **not a class** but a **module**:

```
ActiveSupport.class
#=> Module
```

To patch the `ActiveSupport::TestCase` class, try this:

```
module ActiveSupport
  class TestCase
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the resolution. Updating my question with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  [...]
end
```

`ActiveSupport` is a *module*, not a class. It's being used as a namespace here for the `TestCase` class. Here's the relevant bit of code in `active_support` 5.0.2: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.2/activesupport/lib/active_support/test_case.rb#L14